# Build with the Release settings In Visual Studio 2017 Professional

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am new to Visual studio build files, How can I build my application with release settings and Publish application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if you are only asking about the csproj files / dotnet command, but here is how you can do it within the IDE:

You can switch between debug and release configuration simply by using the drop down:

[image]

Or by the Build -> Configuration manager.

To publish, right click on the project and select publish:

[image]

For the `dotnet` command, I suggest you check the [dotnet-build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x) reference where you'll see an example like: `dotnet build --configuration Release`

As for publishing, check out the [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x) command.

Comment: You are the man, what a detailed explanation. Thank you so much